# How to make a step plot using rqt_plot?

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rather than having rqt_plot linearly interpolate between points, is it possible to create a step plot instead?

Current usage: rqt_plot /velocity/data ,where velocity is a topic I've made.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91411/how-to-make-a-step-plot-using-rqt_plot?/) by [connor](https://answers.ros.org/users/7806/connor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not a feature currently implemented.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0